# creating multiple objects by looping through 2D array?

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array, leaflet, p5.js

I'm new to programming in general and workig with p5.js and Leaflet.
I am trying to draw multiple circles on a map with Leaflet.
I have the coordinates of the capitals of all the countries in the world in a 2D-array.
I am looping through the array to create a circle marker for each row of coordinates. It works so far, but the problem is, that i really only get one circle object, called "circle" with only one pair of coordinates. 
My Question: How can i create a new object with a different name for every loop, so every circle is really an individual object, that can handle events individually?

Here is the code so far:

```js
var coords = [
  [+41.3317, +19.8172],
  [+42.5075, +1.5218],
  [+53.9678, +27.5766],
  [+50.8371, +4.3676],
  [+43.8608, +18.4214],
  [+42.7105, +23.3238],
  [+55.6763, +12.5681],
  [+52.5235, +13.4115],
  [+59.4389, +24.7545],
  [+60.1699, +24.9384],
  [+48.8567, +2.3510],
  [+37.9792, +23.7166],
  [+51.5002, -0.1262],
  [+53.3441, -6.2675],
  [+64.1353, -21.8952],
  [+41.8955, +12.4823],
  [+42.6740, +21.1788],
  [+45.8150, +15.9785],
  [+56.9465, +24.1049],
  [+47.1411, +9.5215],
  [+54.6896, +25.2799],
  [+49.6100, +6.1296],
  [+35.9042, +14.5189],
  [+47.0167, +28.8497],
  [+43.7325, +7.4189],
  [+42.4602, +19.2595],
  [+52.3738, +4.8910],
  [+42.0024, +21.4361],
  [+59.9138, +10.7387],
  [+48.2092, +16.3728],
  [+52.2297, +21.0122],
  [+38.7072, -9.1355],
  [+44.4479, +26.0979],
  [+55.7558, +37.6176],
  [+43.9424, +12.4578],
  [+59.3328, +18.0645],
  [+46.9480, +7.4481],
  [+44.8048, +20.4781],
  [+48.2116, +17.1547],
  [+46.0514, +14.5060],
  [+40.4167, -3.7033],
  [+50.0878, +14.4205],
  [+50.4422, +30.5367],
  [+47.4984, +19.0408],
  [+62.0177, -6.7719],
  [+36.1377, -5.3453],
  [+49.4660, -2.5522],
  [+54.1670, -4.4821],
  [+49.1919, -2.1071],
  [+78.2186, +15.6488],
  [+34.5155, +69.1952],
  [+40.1596, +44.5090],
  [+40.3834, +49.8932],
  [+26.1921, +50.5354],
  [+23.7106, +90.3978],
  [+27.4405, +89.6730],
  [+4.9431, +114.9425],
  [+39.9056, +116.3958],
  [+41.7010, +44.7930],
  [+28.6353, +77.2250],
  [-6.1862, +106.8063],
  [+33.3157, +44.3922],
  [+35.7061, +51.4358],
  [+31.7857, +35.2007],
  [+35.6785, +139.6823],
  [+15.3556, +44.2081],
  [+31.9394, +35.9349],
  [+11.5434, +104.8984],
  [+51.1796, +71.4475],
  [+25.2948, +51.5082],
  [+42.8679, +74.5984],
  [+29.3721, +47.9824],
  [+17.9689, +102.6137],
  [+33.8872, +35.5134],
  [+3.1502, +101.7077],
  [+4.1742, +73.5109],
  [+47.9138, +106.9220],
  [+19.7378, +96.2083],
  [+27.7058, +85.3157],
  [+39.0187, +125.7468],
  [+23.6086, +58.5922],
  [+33.6751, +73.0946],
  [+14.5790, +120.9726],
  [+24.6748, +46.6977],
  [+1.2894, +103.8500],
  [+6.9155, +79.8572],
  [+33.5158, +36.2939],
  [+37.5139, +126.9828],
  [+38.5737, +68.7738],
  [+13.7573, +100.5020],
  [-8.5662, +125.5880],
  [+39.9439, +32.8560],
  [+37.9509, +58.3794],
  [+41.3193, +69.2481],
  [+24.4764, +54.3705],
  [+21.0341, +105.8372],
  [+35.1676, +33.3736],
  [+25.0338, +121.5645],
  [+17.1175, -61.8456],
  [-34.6118, -58.4173],
  [+25.0661, -77.3390],
  [+13.0935, -59.6105],
  [+17.2534, -88.7713],
  [-19.0421, -65.2559],
  [-15.7801, -47.9292],
  [-33.4691, -70.6420],
  [+9.9402, -84.1002],
  [+15.2976, -61.3900],
  [+18.4790, -69.8908],
  [-0.2295, -78.5243],
  [+13.7034, -89.2073],
  [+12.0540, -61.7486],
  [+14.6248, -90.5328],
  [+6.8046, -58.1548],
  [+18.5392, -72.3288],
  [+14.0821, -87.2063],
  [+17.9927, -76.7920],
  [+45.4235, -75.6979],
  [+4.6473, -74.0962],
  [+23.1333, -82.3667],
  [+19.4271, -99.1276],
  [+12.1475, -86.2734],
  [+8.9943, -79.5188],
  [-25.3005, -57.6362],
  [-12.0931, -77.0465],
  [+17.2968, -62.7138],
  [+13.9972, -61.0018],
  [+13.2035, -61.2653],
  [+5.8232, -55.1679],
  [+10.6596, -61.4789],
  [-34.8941, -56.0675],
  [+10.4961, -66.8983],
  [+38.8921, -77.0241],
  [+18.3405, -64.9326],
  [+18.2249, -63.0669],
  [+12.5246, -70.0265],
  [+32.2930, -64.7820],
  [+18.4328, -64.6235],
  [+19.3022, -81.3857],
  [-51.7010, -57.8492],
  [+4.9346, -52.3303],
  [+64.1836, -51.7214],
  [+15.9985, -61.7220],
  [+14.5997, -61.0760],
  [+16.6802, -62.2014],
  [+12.1034, -68.9335],
  [+18.4500, -66.0667],
  [+46.7878, -56.1968],
  [+21.4608, -71.1363],
  [+30.0571, +31.2272],
  [+36.7755, +3.0597],
  [-8.8159, +13.2306],
  [+3.7523, +8.7741],
  [+9.0084, +38.7575],
  [+6.4779, +2.6323],
  [-24.6570, +25.9089],
  [+12.3569, -1.5352],
  [-3.3818, +29.3622],
  [+6.8067, -5.2728],
  [+11.5806, +43.1425],
  [+15.3315, +38.9183],
  [+0.3858, +9.4496],
  [+13.4399, -16.6775],
  [+5.5401, -0.2074],
  [+9.5370, -13.6785],
  [+11.8598, -15.5875],
  [+3.8612, +11.5217],
  [+14.9195, -23.5153],
  [-1.2762, +36.7965],
  [-11.7004, +43.2412],
  [-4.2767, +15.2662],
  [-4.3369, +15.3271],
  [-29.2976, +27.4854],
  [+6.3106, -10.8047],
  [+32.8830, +13.1897],
  [-18.9201, +47.5237],
  [-13.9899, +33.7703],
  [+12.6530, -7.9864],
  [+33.9905, -6.8704],
  [+18.0669, -15.9900],
  [-20.1654, +57.4896],
  [-25.9686, +32.5804],
  [-22.5749, +17.0805],
  [+13.5164, +2.1157],
  [+9.0580, +7.4891],
  [-1.9441, +30.0619],
  [-15.4145, +28.2809],
  [+0.3360, +6.7311],
  [+14.6953, -17.4439],
  [-4.6167, +55.4500],
  [+8.4697, -13.2659],
  [-17.8227, +31.0496],
  [+2.0411, +45.3426],
  [+15.5501, +32.5322],
  [+4.8496, +31.6046],
  [-26.3186, +31.1410],
  [-25.7463, +28.1876],
  [-6.1670, +35.7497],
  [+6.1228, +1.2255],
  [+12.1121, +15.0355],
  [+36.8117, +10.1761],
  [+0.3133, +32.5714],
  [+4.3621, +18.5873],
  [-12.7806, +45.2278],
  [-20.8732, +55.4603],
  [-15.9244, -5.7181],
  [+27.1536, -13.2033],
  [-35.2820, +149.1286],
  [-18.1416, +178.4419],
  [+1.3282, +172.9784],
  [+7.1167, +171.3667],
  [+6.9177, +158.1854],
  [-0.5434, +166.9196],
  [-41.2865, +174.7762],
  [+7.5007, +134.6241],
  [-9.4656, +147.1969],
  [-9.4333, +159.9500],
  [-13.8314, -171.7518],
  [-21.1360, -175.2164],
  [-8.5210, +179.1983],
  [-17.7404, +168.3210],
  [-14.2793, -170.7009],
  [-21.2039, -159.7658],
  [-17.5350, -149.5696],
  [+13.4667, +144.7470],
  [-12.1869, +96.8283],
  [-22.2758, +166.4581],
  [-19.0565, -169.9237],
  [+15.2069, +145.7197],
  [-29.0545, +167.9666],
  [-25.0662, -130.1027],
  [-13.2784, -176.1430],
  [-10.4286, +105.6807],
  [+32.3754, -86.2996],
  [+58.3637, -134.5721],
  [+33.4483, -112.0738],
  [+34.7244, -92.2789],
  [+38.5737, -121.4871],
  [+39.7551, -104.9881],
  [+41.7665, -72.6732],
  [+39.1615, -75.5136],
  [+30.4382, -84.2806],
  [+33.7545, -84.3897],
  [+21.2920, -157.8219],
  [+43.6021, -116.2125],
  [+39.8018, -89.6533],
  [+39.7670, -86.1563],
  [+41.5888, -93.6203],
  [+39.0474, -95.6815],
  [+38.1894, -84.8715],
  [+30.4493, -91.1882],
  [+44.3294, -69.7323],
  [+38.9693, -76.5197],
  [+42.3589, -71.0568],
  [+42.7336, -84.5466],
  [+44.9446, -93.1027],
  [+32.3122, -90.1780],
  [+38.5698, -92.1941],
  [+46.5911, -112.0205],
  [+40.8136, -96.7026],
  [+39.1501, -119.7519],
  [+43.2314, -71.5597],
  [+40.2202, -74.7642],
  [+35.6816, -105.9381],
  [+42.6517, -73.7551],
  [+35.7797, -78.6434],
  [+46.8084, -100.7694],
  [+39.9622, -83.0007],
  [+35.4931, -97.4591],
  [+44.9370, -123.0272],
  [+40.2740, -76.8849],
  [+41.8270, -71.4087],
  [+34.0007, -81.0353],
  [+44.3776, -100.3177],
  [+36.1589, -86.7821],
  [+30.2687, -97.7452],
  [+40.7716, -111.8882],
  [+44.2627, -72.5716],
  [+37.5408, -77.4339],
  [+47.0449, -122.9016],
  [+38.3533, -81.6354],
  [+43.0632, -89.4007],
  [+41.1389, -104.8165]
];

var newCoords = [];
var circleIndex = [];
var circle;

function setup() {

  //Initializig the map


  mapId = createDiv();
  mapId.id("mapid");
  mapId.size(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  mapId.position(0, 0)
  mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 2.5);


  //Loading tiles from mapbox

  L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib3NrYXItcXVpcmluLWthY2tlYmFydCIsImEiOiJjazV4b2EyM2UyMWdtM2VtbG0wdzFvM2p2In0.SrMgYWTBUYDq3f703br1aQ'
  }).addTo(mymap);

  //creating the circles on the map

  for (i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    circleIndex[i] = []
    for (j = 0; j < coords[i].length; j++) {
      circleIndex[i].push(coords[i][j]);
      newCoords.push(coords[i][j]);
    }
    circle = L.circle(newCoords, {
      color: 'red',
      fillColor: '#f03',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      radius: 50000
    }).addTo(mymap);
    newCoords = []

    //adding callback function to a click event for the circle. This will only work for the circle with the Index 1 of the array.

  }
  circle.on('click', function(click) {
    alert(this.latlng);
  });

}
```

Any suggestions, how to get a grasp on that? Can I maybe change the constructor somehow to add a different name-index for each row-index or something?

Sorry for the messy code ^^ I am open to edit-suggestions as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not storing the circles in an array instead of the circle variable which gets overrided every time in the loop? The circleIndex array is not being used for anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep a reference to each circle, you can either add them to an array or a dict. I would use an array since you don't have anything to distinguish each circle like a string name.

Here is how I would edit the code.

Remember to also declare as `var i` or `let i` the variables inside the loops.

```js
var coords = [
  [+41.3317, +19.8172],
  [+42.5075, +1.5218],
  [+53.9678, +27.5766],
  [+50.8371, +4.3676],
  [+43.8608, +18.4214],
  [+42.7105, +23.3238],
  [+55.6763, +12.5681],
  [+52.5235, +13.4115],
  [+59.4389, +24.7545],
  [+60.1699, +24.9384],
  [+48.8567, +2.3510],
  [+37.9792, +23.7166],
  [+51.5002, -0.1262],
  [+53.3441, -6.2675],
  [+64.1353, -21.8952],
  [+41.8955, +12.4823],
  [+42.6740, +21.1788],
  [+45.8150, +15.9785],
  [+56.9465, +24.1049],
  [+47.1411, +9.5215],
  [+54.6896, +25.2799],
  [+49.6100, +6.1296],
  [+35.9042, +14.5189],
  [+47.0167, +28.8497],
  [+43.7325, +7.4189],
  [+42.4602, +19.2595],
  [+52.3738, +4.8910],
  [+42.0024, +21.4361],
  [+59.9138, +10.7387],
  [+48.2092, +16.3728],
  [+52.2297, +21.0122],
  [+38.7072, -9.1355],
  [+44.4479, +26.0979],
  [+55.7558, +37.6176],
  [+43.9424, +12.4578],
  [+59.3328, +18.0645],
  [+46.9480, +7.4481],
  [+44.8048, +20.4781],
  [+48.2116, +17.1547],
  [+46.0514, +14.5060],
  [+40.4167, -3.7033],
  [+50.0878, +14.4205],
  [+50.4422, +30.5367],
  [+47.4984, +19.0408],
  [+62.0177, -6.7719],
  [+36.1377, -5.3453],
  [+49.4660, -2.5522],
  [+54.1670, -4.4821],
  [+49.1919, -2.1071],
  [+78.2186, +15.6488],
  [+34.5155, +69.1952],
  [+40.1596, +44.5090],
  [+40.3834, +49.8932],
  [+26.1921, +50.5354],
  [+23.7106, +90.3978],
  [+27.4405, +89.6730],
  [+4.9431, +114.9425],
  [+39.9056, +116.3958],
  [+41.7010, +44.7930],
  [+28.6353, +77.2250],
  [-6.1862, +106.8063],
  [+33.3157, +44.3922],
  [+35.7061, +51.4358],
  [+31.7857, +35.2007],
  [+35.6785, +139.6823],
  [+15.3556, +44.2081],
  [+31.9394, +35.9349],
  [+11.5434, +104.8984],
  [+51.1796, +71.4475],
  [+25.2948, +51.5082],
  [+42.8679, +74.5984],
  [+29.3721, +47.9824],
  [+17.9689, +102.6137],
  [+33.8872, +35.5134],
  [+3.1502, +101.7077],
  [+4.1742, +73.5109],
  [+47.9138, +106.9220],
  [+19.7378, +96.2083],
  [+27.7058, +85.3157],
  [+39.0187, +125.7468],
  [+23.6086, +58.5922],
  [+33.6751, +73.0946],
  [+14.5790, +120.9726],
  [+24.6748, +46.6977],
  [+1.2894, +103.8500],
  [+6.9155, +79.8572],
  [+33.5158, +36.2939],
  [+37.5139, +126.9828],
  [+38.5737, +68.7738],
  [+13.7573, +100.5020],
  [-8.5662, +125.5880],
  [+39.9439, +32.8560],
  [+37.9509, +58.3794],
  [+41.3193, +69.2481],
  [+24.4764, +54.3705],
  [+21.0341, +105.8372],
  [+35.1676, +33.3736],
  [+25.0338, +121.5645],
  [+17.1175, -61.8456],
  [-34.6118, -58.4173],
  [+25.0661, -77.3390],
  [+13.0935, -59.6105],
  [+17.2534, -88.7713],
  [-19.0421, -65.2559],
  [-15.7801, -47.9292],
  [-33.4691, -70.6420],
  [+9.9402, -84.1002],
  [+15.2976, -61.3900],
  [+18.4790, -69.8908],
  [-0.2295, -78.5243],
  [+13.7034, -89.2073],
  [+12.0540, -61.7486],
  [+14.6248, -90.5328],
  [+6.8046, -58.1548],
  [+18.5392, -72.3288],
  [+14.0821, -87.2063],
  [+17.9927, -76.7920],
  [+45.4235, -75.6979],
  [+4.6473, -74.0962],
  [+23.1333, -82.3667],
  [+19.4271, -99.1276],
  [+12.1475, -86.2734],
  [+8.9943, -79.5188],
  [-25.3005, -57.6362],
  [-12.0931, -77.0465],
  [+17.2968, -62.7138],
  [+13.9972, -61.0018],
  [+13.2035, -61.2653],
  [+5.8232, -55.1679],
  [+10.6596, -61.4789],
  [-34.8941, -56.0675],
  [+10.4961, -66.8983],
  [+38.8921, -77.0241],
  [+18.3405, -64.9326],
  [+18.2249, -63.0669],
  [+12.5246, -70.0265],
  [+32.2930, -64.7820],
  [+18.4328, -64.6235],
  [+19.3022, -81.3857],
  [-51.7010, -57.8492],
  [+4.9346, -52.3303],
  [+64.1836, -51.7214],
  [+15.9985, -61.7220],
  [+14.5997, -61.0760],
  [+16.6802, -62.2014],
  [+12.1034, -68.9335],
  [+18.4500, -66.0667],
  [+46.7878, -56.1968],
  [+21.4608, -71.1363],
  [+30.0571, +31.2272],
  [+36.7755, +3.0597],
  [-8.8159, +13.2306],
  [+3.7523, +8.7741],
  [+9.0084, +38.7575],
  [+6.4779, +2.6323],
  [-24.6570, +25.9089],
  [+12.3569, -1.5352],
  [-3.3818, +29.3622],
  [+6.8067, -5.2728],
  [+11.5806, +43.1425],
  [+15.3315, +38.9183],
  [+0.3858, +9.4496],
  [+13.4399, -16.6775],
  [+5.5401, -0.2074],
  [+9.5370, -13.6785],
  [+11.8598, -15.5875],
  [+3.8612, +11.5217],
  [+14.9195, -23.5153],
  [-1.2762, +36.7965],
  [-11.7004, +43.2412],
  [-4.2767, +15.2662],
  [-4.3369, +15.3271],
  [-29.2976, +27.4854],
  [+6.3106, -10.8047],
  [+32.8830, +13.1897],
  [-18.9201, +47.5237],
  [-13.9899, +33.7703],
  [+12.6530, -7.9864],
  [+33.9905, -6.8704],
  [+18.0669, -15.9900],
  [-20.1654, +57.4896],
  [-25.9686, +32.5804],
  [-22.5749, +17.0805],
  [+13.5164, +2.1157],
  [+9.0580, +7.4891],
  [-1.9441, +30.0619],
  [-15.4145, +28.2809],
  [+0.3360, +6.7311],
  [+14.6953, -17.4439],
  [-4.6167, +55.4500],
  [+8.4697, -13.2659],
  [-17.8227, +31.0496],
  [+2.0411, +45.3426],
  [+15.5501, +32.5322],
  [+4.8496, +31.6046],
  [-26.3186, +31.1410],
  [-25.7463, +28.1876],
  [-6.1670, +35.7497],
  [+6.1228, +1.2255],
  [+12.1121, +15.0355],
  [+36.8117, +10.1761],
  [+0.3133, +32.5714],
  [+4.3621, +18.5873],
  [-12.7806, +45.2278],
  [-20.8732, +55.4603],
  [-15.9244, -5.7181],
  [+27.1536, -13.2033],
  [-35.2820, +149.1286],
  [-18.1416, +178.4419],
  [+1.3282, +172.9784],
  [+7.1167, +171.3667],
  [+6.9177, +158.1854],
  [-0.5434, +166.9196],
  [-41.2865, +174.7762],
  [+7.5007, +134.6241],
  [-9.4656, +147.1969],
  [-9.4333, +159.9500],
  [-13.8314, -171.7518],
  [-21.1360, -175.2164],
  [-8.5210, +179.1983],
  [-17.7404, +168.3210],
  [-14.2793, -170.7009],
  [-21.2039, -159.7658],
  [-17.5350, -149.5696],
  [+13.4667, +144.7470],
  [-12.1869, +96.8283],
  [-22.2758, +166.4581],
  [-19.0565, -169.9237],
  [+15.2069, +145.7197],
  [-29.0545, +167.9666],
  [-25.0662, -130.1027],
  [-13.2784, -176.1430],
  [-10.4286, +105.6807],
  [+32.3754, -86.2996],
  [+58.3637, -134.5721],
  [+33.4483, -112.0738],
  [+34.7244, -92.2789],
  [+38.5737, -121.4871],
  [+39.7551, -104.9881],
  [+41.7665, -72.6732],
  [+39.1615, -75.5136],
  [+30.4382, -84.2806],
  [+33.7545, -84.3897],
  [+21.2920, -157.8219],
  [+43.6021, -116.2125],
  [+39.8018, -89.6533],
  [+39.7670, -86.1563],
  [+41.5888, -93.6203],
  [+39.0474, -95.6815],
  [+38.1894, -84.8715],
  [+30.4493, -91.1882],
  [+44.3294, -69.7323],
  [+38.9693, -76.5197],
  [+42.3589, -71.0568],
  [+42.7336, -84.5466],
  [+44.9446, -93.1027],
  [+32.3122, -90.1780],
  [+38.5698, -92.1941],
  [+46.5911, -112.0205],
  [+40.8136, -96.7026],
  [+39.1501, -119.7519],
  [+43.2314, -71.5597],
  [+40.2202, -74.7642],
  [+35.6816, -105.9381],
  [+42.6517, -73.7551],
  [+35.7797, -78.6434],
  [+46.8084, -100.7694],
  [+39.9622, -83.0007],
  [+35.4931, -97.4591],
  [+44.9370, -123.0272],
  [+40.2740, -76.8849],
  [+41.8270, -71.4087],
  [+34.0007, -81.0353],
  [+44.3776, -100.3177],
  [+36.1589, -86.7821],
  [+30.2687, -97.7452],
  [+40.7716, -111.8882],
  [+44.2627, -72.5716],
  [+37.5408, -77.4339],
  [+47.0449, -122.9016],
  [+38.3533, -81.6354],
  [+43.0632, -89.4007],
  [+41.1389, -104.8165]
];

//var newCoords = []; // this is only used inside the loop so it can be declared there
//var circleIndex = []; // this is not being used
//var circle; // this gets overridden on each iteration 
var circles = []; // Use this array to store the created circles

function setup() {

  //Initializig the map


  mapId = createDiv();
  mapId.id("mapid");
  mapId.size(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  mapId.position(0, 0)
  mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 2.5);


  //Loading tiles from mapbox

  L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib3NrYXItcXVpcmluLWthY2tlYmFydCIsImEiOiJjazV4b2EyM2UyMWdtM2VtbG0wdzFvM2p2In0.SrMgYWTBUYDq3f703br1aQ'
  }).addTo(mymap);

  //creating the circles on the map

  // Tip: Instead of looking at the coords multidimensional array as a matrix, think of
  // it as a list of coordinate pairs, which you can loop without using indexes
  for (let newCoordPair of coords) {
    var circle = L.circle(newCoordPair, {
      color: 'red',
      fillColor: '#f03',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      radius: 50000
    }).addTo(mymap);

    circles.push(circle);
    // Add here the event to the circle if you want all the circles to have it
    circle.on('click', function(click) {
       alert(this.latlng);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! That totally serves the purpose! And in addition now I also got the purpose of the "for of" loop! Awesome!